# How does one use an apostrophe when introducing a person and their belonging?

Tags: style-manuals

Daniel runs into Nancy's, his sister's, bedroom.

Daniel runs into Nancy's, his sister, bedroom.

Daniel runs into Nancy, his sister's, bedroom.

---

Out of the three statements above, which one is accurate? How does one use an apostrophe when introducing a person and their belonging?

Comment: @Jim There is no compound subject here but it still goes at the end.

Comment: @tchrist - I guess I parsed it differently.  I concluded that the intent was, “Nancy and his sister’s bedroom.”  It never occurred to me that “*his sister*” was parenthetical.   in that case, “Daniel runs into his sister Nancy’s bedroom” would seem best.

Answer (score 0):

These are nouns in apposition — *Nancy, his sister* — so I would dispense with commas altogether.  This makes it more obvious that the Saxon genitive goes at the end of the noun phrase.

> Daniel runs into Nancy his sister’s bedroom.

It works just like:

> Daniel runs into his sister Nancy’s bedroom.

Comment: For the first sentence, the preposition *into* needs an object. I don't see how that's gonna be anything other than *Nancy*. The bedroom needs an owner. That's not gonna be *Nancy*, which has no possessive sense; it will rather be in the form of *sister's*.

Comment: @deadrat I'm afraid I don't see what you're saying. *Bedroom* is the object he runs into in both sentences.

Comment: *Bedroom* is the object he *wants* to run into, but *Nancy* is in the way, syntactically speaking.