# where to put the possessive "s" with an appositive parenthetical

Tags: possessives, clauses

Say I have a gym instructor called Anne and it's her birthday. I want to convey that to someone who doesn't know who Anne is in one sentence.

In speech, I would probably say, "it is Anne, my gym instructor's, birthday." But, in writing, that seems wrong; it puts the possessive "s" in the subclause only.

So what is the correct way to write a sentence like this? "It is Anne's, my gym instructor's, birthday"? "It is Anne's, my gym instructor, birthday"? Something else?

Comment: _It is the birthday of Anne, my gym instructor_ :)

Comment: But seriously, there's nothing wrong with the possessive at the end of the subclause. Compare _The king of England's crown_, where the _-s_ is at the end of the noun group.

Comment: I don't think you should have a comma after ***Anne*** if you're going to use that as part of a longer string of words to be modified by the Saxon genitive apostrophe. Which by implication means you don't want the comma *after* the apostrophe either.

Comment: Better to convert the descriptive subclause to a standard noun adjunct:  "It is my gym instructor Anne's birthday."

Comment: Why is that better, @Hellion?

Comment: ""it is Anne, my gym instructor's, birthday." This is fine, in writing or speech.

Comment: @ColinFine because it lets you avoid the issue entirely.  :-)

Comment: I wanted to cite [How does one use an apostrophe when introducing a person and their belonging?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353773/how-does-one-use-an-apostrophe-when-introducing-a-person-and-their-belonging/353775) as a duplicate, because it specifically asks about the orthography of ***Daniel runs into Nancy's, his sister's, bedroom.*** (I might myself go for that "double genitive" as making the best of a bad job.) But it has no upvotes, so it's ineligible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe this question is a duplicate of the first post you mentioned - although having no upvotes on the answer is a shame - but not the second.

Comment: *It is Anne's birthday (my gym teacher).*

Comment: @Hellion: so what if it lets you avoid the issue? Why does that make it better? It's not an issue for most English speakers, so why is it better to avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with the possessive marker at the end. Compare *The king of England's crown*, where the *-s* is at the end of the noun group.

It does sound a bit more awkward if you have a whole apposition following the head noun, but syntactically it looks fine to me.

Or you could write *It is my gym instructor Anne's birthday.*

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken but I always deem it correct to put a description of a person in a new clause within commas: "Edward, the King of England, has a crown". So in that instance, would it be "Edward, the King of England's, crown"?

Comment: @TimBarclay Yes, I would think so.

Comment: << Anne, my gym instructor's, birthday >> and << The king of England's crown >> are different forms. We're guessing if we model one's behaviour on the other's. Have you a corroborating reference for 'There's nothing wrong with the possessive marker at the end '?