# How to add possessive to comma clause specifying pronoun?

Tags: punctuation, comma-splices

Not exactly sure what the comma rule is called, but how would I add a possessive in the following sentence where the dog belongs to David?

> I had to take my brother, David, ('s?) dog to the vet.

Comment: 'whose' is the word for 'of whom'.

Comment: If you have only one brother, this short sentence may be the wrong place to name him. "I had to take my brother's dog to the vet" is already enough information.

Comment: A duplicate of [Where to pu the possessive 's with an appositive parenthetical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449567/where-to-put-the-possessive-s-with-an-appositive-parenthetical), which contains no satisfactory answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Got it, thank you