# How do I show possession when I use a non-restrictive clause

Tags: possessives, non-restrictive

For example, if John has a bike.
It's John's bike.
It's John, a colleague of mine, 's bike.
How do you really write that?

I know I can just say "It's the bike of John, a colleague of mine," but that doesn't sound as clean as using 's.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appositives with possessiveness?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57700/appositives-with-possessiveness) [And this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449567/where-to-put-the-possessive-s-with-an-appositive-parenthetical).